# How to access current folder in a Forge - Design automation app

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have created a forge app, for revit, using the provided deleteapps design automation template, and the design automation API. The goal of this app is to process and export content from revit file.

My question is, how to get the current working directory, in the app, when a workitem starts?

```
public void HandleDesignAutomationReadyEvent(object sender, DesignAutomationReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Succeeded = true;
        Export(e.DesignAutomationData);
    }
```

There is `ModelPathUtils.ConvertUserVisiblePathToModelPath(model);` but I dont want a path to a revit file, just a base path, where I can create folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design Automation allows you to write to current working folder. It is a unique path for each job. You can call [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=net-6.0) to access the current folder.

```cs
string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

This will give you the root folder for a given job. You are allowed to create sub folders and save files within this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the current `RVT` `Document` [`PathName` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/8a92a6fd-ce25-cd86-2068-f9dcb24d72d6.htm). Not sure whether it lives in the current directory, though, but it might be interesting to check.

Comment: I didn't specify in the question, but I don't want to provide the file name in the request, to make the app more general, so I don't have that parameter filled. The result of getting the contents was that the working directory contains the passed revit file (or revit files) renamed to a -guid-.rvt, and the log file for the session